# uncaught exception: could not open file

Tags: php, uploadcare

so i'm trying to upload to uploadcare cdn and i get this error: Uncaught Exception: couldn't open file "ce3577f708f527ff570e0d21acb39c62.jpg"

```
$description = $_POST['uploaddesc'];
  list($width,$height) = getimagesize($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name']);
 $extensions  = array('image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/tiff');
 $move = 'uploads/';
 $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);


$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadimage']['name']);
if(!$_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name']){
$errors[]="Please choose an image";
}
if(empty($description)){
    $errors[]='Please choose a description for the image';
}
//IF IMAGE IS UPLOADED..
if($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name']){
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name']);
```

// IF MIME FAILES OR GETIMAGESIZE IS NULL (meaning its no an image)
        if(!getimagesize($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name']) && !in_array($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'],$mime)){
       $errors[]='Please choose an image';
       unset($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name']);
          }

```
     if(empty($errors)){

 $randString = md5(time()); //encode the timestamp - returns a 32 chars long string
 $fileName = $_FILES["uploadimage"]["name"]; //the original file name
 $splitName = explode(".", $fileName); //split the file name by the dot
 $fileExt = end($splitName); //get the file extension
 $newFileName  = strtolower($randString.'.'.$fileExt); //join file name and ext.
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'], $move . $newFileName)){
 $description = $_POST['uploaddesc']; 
 $user->insertArt($description, 'uploads/' . $newFileName, $user->getUsername($_SESSION['username']));
 $file = $api->uploader->fromPath('uploads/' . $newFileName);
 $file->store();    

//throw new ErrorException('MEMORY USAGE ' . memory_get_peak_usage());


 }
     }

}
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: why am i getting this error

Comment: Where abouts in the code is this error referring? What line? Have you made sure there's no requirements to meet in whatever function you're using when uploading? like filename length?

Comment: the error seems to come uploadcare uploader.php?   private function __runRequest($ch)
  {
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $ch_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if ($data === false) {
      throw new \Exception(curl_error($ch));
    }

Comment: so it's a curl.. error?

Comment: What does your full error message say?

Comment: @Lee im sorry i have fixed it. i had to use realpath('uploads/' . $newfilename);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed it. i had to use realpath('uploads/' . $newfilename);